# How to find an element in a container before a given starting position?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I would like to find the **last** occurrence of an element in a container before some given starting position.

For instance, if I'm trying to find the last space before a given character in a string 's', I believe the obvious approach would be something like:

```
string::const_iterator b;
b = i; // <-- 'i' specifies where to start looking
while ((b != s.begin()) && (b[-1] != ' '))
    b--;
```

Is there a better way to do this using STL algorithms?

---

I've tried:

```
b = find(string::const_reverse_iterator(i),
string::const_reverse_iterator(s.begin()), " ").base();
```

But I'm not sure if this works as intended.

Comment: @DieterLücking I really don't. I ask if there's a **better** way to do this task with STL algorithms. If there isn't then I'm ok with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic purposes, I think I would use [std::find_end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_end) with an adequate lambda function. The example on the page illustrates well the function's behavior.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Except that I thought that if find_end(b,e,b2,e2) didn't find any occurrences it would return b, instead of e.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::string::find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) and specify where it should search no farther than.  The following will find the position of the first space before the word test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "this is a test string";
    auto pos = foo.find_last_of(" ", foo.find("test", 0));
    std::cout << pos;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9
```

Comment: 1 - That only works with strings. Although my example was about strings, my question was about containers in general
2 - I don't think that's better in any way than what I suggested. I can at least say that it isn't probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse iterator solution will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using std::string;
    using const_iterator = string::const_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator = string::const_reverse_iterator;
    string s("This is an sample");
    const_iterator pos = s.begin() + s.find("sample");
    const_reverse_iterator result = std::find(const_reverse_iterator(pos), s.crend(), 's');
    std::cout << string(s.cbegin(), result.base()) << '\n';
}
```

However, you might prefer the solution of @NathanOliver.